# Rails: pass has_many or belongs_to attribute in 'generate' command

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm trying to make a scaffold but want to pass a has_many attribute to the generate command as follows:

```
rails generate scaffold grade name:string {has_many :sections}
```

This generates the broken model:

```
class Grade < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :, :name, :{has_many
end
```

instead of what i need:

```
class Grade < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :name
  has_many :sections
end
```

How can i pass a relationship attribute to the generate command?

Answer (score 11):

Currently the only thing that you can do with scaffolding is adding a reference in the model you want the belongs_to

```
rails generate model Sections name:string grade:references
```

There are ways to generate with relations, but it is not Rails standard scaffolding. There are a lot of options to do that like:

[Ubiquo_Scaffold](http://blog.ubiquo.me/now-on-edge-easier-relations-in-scaffold-gene)